# S3Client BeginGetObject/EndGetObject doesn't throw relevant exception

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Aws S3 method like `GetObject` throws `AmazonS3Exception` with a relevant code - like `MissingKey`, `MissingBucket`, etc. But, this what I discovered with using the async method pair `BeginGetObject/EndGetObject` is that exceptions thrown aren't correct. They are generic exception and not specific amazonS3Exceptions. So, for a missing file I will not get `AmazonS3Exception` and instead get `NullReferenceException`. Is this a bug with the async method pair?
I am using AWSSDK 2.3.55.2

Comment: you can get the source from github. Compile and trace it to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bug in 2.3.55.2 (and I guess this is true for all 2.x versions). Upgrading to 3.x is the only option.